# Can I use TYPO3's RTE in a front end plugin?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I have a custom extension, and i need to use some form of text editor in the front-end. According to the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/rtehtmlarea/Configuration/FrontEndPlugins/Index.html), it should be possible, but the documentation and tutorials seem to be deprecated. I think this is not available in typo3 7.6 :

```
require_once(t3lib_extMgm::extPath('rtehtmlarea').'pi2/class.tx_rtehtmlarea_pi2.php');
```

Can it be done somehow or do i need to install another extension for this, maybe just a viewhelper? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, that feature worked only in theory and never in reality. Use an RTE like ckeditor or whatever fits best

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i did end up using a simple javascript editor, i will leave the question open for a while, in case someone actually managed to use it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I did lots of researches trying to use the rtehtmlarea in the FE, but failed. Then, I realized I could use any RTE, as they are nothing but js+css. All I need is to render the contents with `RTE.FE`, like how the BE does, and save the result into the database, which is all I want. I have already done this in many sites, using standalone tinymce, and it works great. So, I think maybe you could try this solution.

Comment: Thank you, in the end I ended up using a simple javascript based editor. It is really annoying, because according to the documentation, it should be possible, and not that hard to implement